# Computer without Graphic Card, Asus P8P67

Tags: linux, boot, bios

I'm having some requirement to built a computer without Graphic Card (no inboard, no external, nothing).

The OS installation (Linux) and setup will use an external Graphic Card for sure, but after that,  the card will be taken off the board, and all administration will be done via SSH.

So the question is, can the computer boots up WITHOUT any Graphic Card attached?

The motherboard is Asus P8P67-MPRO.

Comment: why don't i try it myself? because i don't have the Motherboard yet, if this is possible, i'll buy it.

Comment: Are you sure it *can't* have a graphics card, or just that the computer has a graphic card, but can't have a monitor connected to it?  As Douglas mentions below, most bios chips won't pass POST without a card at least being there...

Comment: @mike
perhaps the question should be, can motherboard ASUS P8P67 boot without Graphic Card? is there any way to disable (something like) "halt on error" on the BIOS ? so the BIOS ignore the presence of Graphic Card. Thanks.

Comment: Many things are possible with [coreboot](http://www.coreboot.org/Welcome_to_coreboot); I don't know whether they support your motherboard, but it's a place to start looking

Comment: can't find ASUS P8P67 on its supported boards list. any experience with this board?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK most PCs won't boot without a graphics card available.

Comment: that's what i'm first thinking, but http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1223912 gives me some hope.

Comment: As said there: "Have a fiddle with the "Halt on Error" setting in the BIOS."

Comment: The answer to ["Is it possible to RDP into Windows Server 2008 on a machine without any video card or integrated graphics?"](http://superuser.com/questions/472391/is-it-possible-to-rdp-into-windows-server-2008-on-a-machine-without-any-video-ca) claims that it is possible to boot and run a "headless server" without any integrated graphics or plug-in graphics card.

Comment: @DavidCary I think it will depend on the machine - some will boot (although you need to make sure the OS doesn't hang looking for the card), others will just hang (and beep) if they don't find a graphics card. Others will emulate a display over a serial console.

Comment: Yes, Some machines will boot without any video hardware *after* one sets the BIOS to "beep and continue" rather than "beep and halt on any error". (Alas, one often needs to temporarily plug in a video card to be able to set that option). Since I can't seem to find that option in the ["P8P67-M PRO manual"](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67M_PRO/HelpDesk_Manual/), this may be one of the motherboards where the BIOS refuses to boot when it can't find a graphic card.

Comment: Could you add that information to your answer?